# Losing data on formemail when eliminating duplicate values from multiple Select Lists

Tags: javascript, select, input, html-select, onchange

I am using the script example provided above and it is working perfectly on the input page.

```
<script>
    function disableValue(str){
                var dis1=document.getElementsByTagName("option");
                 for(var i=0;i<dis1.length;i++){
                        if(dis1[i].value==str){
                             dis1[i].disabled=true;
                        }
                 }
                return true;
    }

</script>
```

I have 18 separate Select lists each identically seeking user input ranking the items from 18-1. Once a number is used it is grayed out and unavailable in subsequent Select lists exactly as I need.

```
        <select onchange="return disableValue(this.value)" name="game01value">
          <option value="--" >--</option>
          <option value="18"  class="go18">18</option>
          <option value="17"  class="go17">17</option>
          <option value="16"  class="go1"6>16</option>
          <option value="15"  class="go15">15</option>
          <option value="14"  class="go14">14</option>
          <option value="13"  class="go13">13</option>
          <option value="12"  class="go12">12</option>
          <option value="11"  class="go11">11</option>
          <option value="10"  class="go10">10</option>
          <option value="09"  class="go9">09</option>
          <option value="08"  class="go8">08</option>
          <option value="07"  class="go7">07</option>
          <option value="06"  class="go6">06</option>
          <option value="05"  class="go5">05</option>
          <option value="04"  class="go4">04</option>
          <option value="03"  class="go3">03</option>
          <option value="02"  class="go2">02</option>
          <option value="01"  class="go1">01</option>
     </select>
```

However, upon Submitting the input, the `game01value` and other `gameXXvalue` entries on the formemail created are missing. If I remove the Script I receive an entry such as:

```
1. contest = NFL Week 4 (18 Games)
2. emailaddress = boneman@unforgettable.com
3. game01 = Eagles
4. game01value = 18
5. game02 = USC Trojans
6. game02value = 17
7. game03 = Virginia Cavaliers
8. game03value = 16
9. game04 = at Oregon State Beavers
10. game04value = 15
```

but when I insert the script to eliminate duplicate values the same user input results in this:

```
1. contest = NFL Week 4 (18 Games)
2. emailaddress = boneman@unforgettable.com
3. game01 = Eagles
4. game02 = USC Trojans
5. game03 = Virginia Cavaliers
6. game04 = at Oregon State Beavers
```

For some reason the script is not only removing the input number from additional Select lists, it is removing it from my formemail.

My Submit code is:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print and Submit Football Pool" onclick = window.print();>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" >       
<input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="http://www.xxxxxxx/Thank You for Your 
Entry.html">
```

Is there a way to retain the input data selection on the formemail while eliminating the selected value in additional Select lists?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am guessing that becouse the option is disabled the why you use to take the data out of the form is ignoring the disabled field.

So as i see at you have to options.

1. change the way you gather the data from the form.
2. This can be a bit simpler instead of disabling the selected option use display none or had a class that will make them hidden, this one is not pretty but it should give you what your looking for without doing any major changes to the code.

you can use code like this to add style to the div:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
```

Or 
if ill take your code for a more direct approch
i think you can replace the dispabled = true in your code with this:

```
document.getElementById('answer-12702744').style.display = 'none;'
```

Comment: Thank you, once I changed Disabled to Hidden it worked perfectly!

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that if the user changes their mind about a selection the now hidden value does not return to the list. Is there a way to unhide a value after its been been hidden?

Comment: Hmm yes im guessing that the quick and dirty way is to unselect all to unhide all the other values in that option. like if (selected hide), if unselected remove hidden.

I must admit there  should a be a better way to do this, this type of writing will only lead to further troubles down the way.